# How to enable auto versioning on review-edit button?

Tags: workflow

I've created a custom workflow .As per workflow when it is in final state, the workflow will not kick off unless user create a new version and clicks on edit.

**Question:**

1. Is there a way to enable auto version creation on click of
   Review-Edit?
2. Also I m looking at option to enforce auto creation
   irrespective of user role. I want this auto creation should be
   implied to administrator or any logged in user to cms system.

Any help. Let me know if any clarification required.

Comment: Do you want the same approach for those items where workflow is not set? Because you can click on this button even the item doesn't have workflow.

Comment: @Santosh       Can you explain what is the requirement you are trying to solve.

Comment: When there is workflow associated with an item then on click of edit new version should be created by default.

Comment: Requirement: we have 2 state- Draft and Published. We want CMS author or admin if made any changes must go through this workflow. Now for given version once auto publish is done in Published state any changes after that require a new version. This will not happen unless user creates new version . What we want is? Create new version on review-Edit automatically irrespective of user role. Also version is created through version tab or through cms item itself but in case author goes to review and click on edit tab we want to ensure new version is available by default. Hope i m clear now.

Comment: I also looked this option but it states admin user will not  have this option.https://paragdaraji.wordpress.com/2016/05/18/content-editor-create-new-version-automatically-on-edit/

Comment: After exploring more i found these 2 blogs. At the end it got note section where it states : Admin role bypass workflow. https://sitecoreconfig.com/2015/09/14/an-introduction-to-sitecore-workflows-and-publishing-approvals/  https://sitecoreconfig.com/2015/12/22/creating-custom-sitecore-workflows/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a command "item:checkout".

```
<command name="item:checkout" type="type=Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.CheckOut,Sitecore.Kernel"/>
```

Use patch instead to override the command.

```
<command name="item:checkout" type="Sitecore.Custom.Commands.MyCheckOutCommand, Sitecore.Custom" patch:instead="command[@type='type=Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.CheckOut,Sitecore.Kernel']"/>
```

Here is a command. Try something the same.

```
    [Serializable]
public class MyCheckOutCommand : Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.CheckOut
{
    public override void Execute(CommandContext context)
    {
        var item = context.Items[0];
        Database db = item.Database;
        IWorkflow workflow = db.WorkflowProvider.GetWorkflow(item);
        WorkflowState state = workflow.GetState(item);

        if (Sitecore.Context.User.IsInRole("[roleName]") && workflow.WorkflowID == "[WorkflowID]" && state.StateID == "[StateID]")
        {
            item.Versions.AddVersion();
        }
        base.Execute(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sanatosh Poojari Tell me result. The example I provided is for the Edit button in the Review ribbon. But also there is Edit button in the Home ribbon.

Comment: @ vlad shpad I'm in the process of creating a proof of concept.  Yes i m looking at edit button in the review tab.Also the requirement I got is very much in nascent state. I appreciate your help and direction. Thanks.